# Shortcode default variables don't appear

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, shortcode

This is my code

```
function myfunction ( $atts, $content = null ){

$atts = extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'limit' => 1,
'order' => 'ASC',
'columns' => '6'
),$atts));

ob_start(); 
include('php/blogcolumns.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
return $content;
}
add_shortcode('blogcolumns','myfunction');
```

Problem is that default variables don't appear, only when they are added in shortcode, they appear. It shouldn't be like that.
This is shortcode: 
     [blogcolumns limit="" order="" columns=""]

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the attributes that don't have a value. Otherwise you're giving the value of an empty string. So it doesn't take the default value.

e.g

```
[blogcolumns limit="3" columns="3"]
```

Or

```
[blogcolumns limit="5"]
```

Comment: Yeah, if I add only  [blogcolumns] shortcode it works fine with default variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide your HTML, but your construct looks incorrect. What this:

```
$atts = extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'limit' => 1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'columns' => '6'
    ),$atts));
```

does is create variables $limit, $order and $columns (that's what extract() does), and set $atts to an integer (the return from extract).

If your HTML is looking for $atts['somekey'], then it is not going to find it.